# Begin storyboard animation when value receives update

Tags: wpf

In my main window I have a grid that has three rows.  The first row is a header with my application name, the second row contains a text block which has an error message section and the third row contains another grid with a text box and button to log in.

Where my question lies is within the second row.  What I want to do is display the text block with a sliding animation when a string changes value.  I'm not sure who will read this but the value lives within a service.  A service is simply a class that holds properties that you can share between views.  The reason this is important is due to the fact that I have a handful of user controls that I place within the main window.  I can't simply place the 'Message' property in the view model of the main window because I will not always be there.  The 'Message' that I need to display to the user goes in the service so that no matter what view I am in, I can set the 'Message' property and display the error to the user.

Below is my code that animates the text block with no problems.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!--Story board animation that slides down in .5 seconds, displays for 5.5 seconds and then retracts.-->
    <Storyboard x:Key="MessageSlide" AutoReverse="True">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:5.5"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="50"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded"><!--RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded"   t:MessageHandler.CustomTest-->
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MessageSlide}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>

<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Grid.Row="1" Background="{Binding Path=DataService.BackgroundColor}" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" Height="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Text="{Binding Path=DataService.Message, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

What I need to accomplish lies within the 'RoutedEvent' of the 'EventTrigger.'

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
```

Currently what happens is when the main window loads, the sliding animation occurs.  This doesn't really help me out since I need this animation to occur a variable number of times, i.e. when the user clicks on a wrong button, when they enter invalid input etc.  I need to somehow create a custom routed event.  I have looked into these but I have been unable to get them to work.  I imagine there is a way to create this custom routed event to raise when the value in the Data Service changes.  I have been looking at this for a couple of days, but can't seem to get this custom routed event working.  This seems like the right way to go, but if there is a different route any suggestions would be great.  If not, any help with custom routed events would be great as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason AutoReverse didn't work for me here, but the following `Binding.TargetUpdated` event trigger should also do it:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataService.Message, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" ...>
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="50" KeyTime="0:0:0.5"/>
                        <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="50" KeyTime="0:0:10.5"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:11"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was super helpful and very clean compared to what I was trying to do. I saw on msdn that custom events were available so I started there.  I did not see farther down in the documentation that the TargetUpdated was available.